# Adding interaction studio user segment to the journey builder in SFMC with additional fields

Tags: salesforce-marketing-cloud

I have linked user segment to the journey builder. But in data extension which I have used for Journey API as entry source, there I am getting only three fields from user segment.

I want first name, last name and phone number to be added through above flow.

I have those data present in event stream, but still not able to get it into DE.

I want first name, last name and phone number to be added through above flow.

I have those data present in event stream, but still not able to get it into DE.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a triggered campaign for that. If you just sync you segment to journey builder, it will send only fixed field. But with the Triggered campaign you can send any field you have setted as a attribute in Personalization to marketing cloud Data extensions. If I not mistake, there's a template to send to journey builder in any triggered campaign you create. You can select the "segment join" on campaign rule so anytime a user enter the segment, it'll go to the Data Extension with the fields you need.